# Selecting points in dataset that belong to a multivariate Gaussian distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gaussian, multivariate-testing

I have a set of values D:

```
 [[  6.83822474   3.54843586]
 [ 12.45778114   4.42755159]
 [ 10.27710359   9.47337879]
 ..., 
 [ 46.55259568  64.73755611]
 [ 51.50842754  44.60132979]
```

Given a Multivariate Gaussian distribution with mean M and covariance V:

1. What is the equivalent multivariate case of a univariate point being within 2 standard deviations of the mean? i.e. assuming I have a univariate distribution with mean A and std B, I can say a point x_i is within 2 standard deviations of the mean if x_i - A < B. What would be the equivalent of this in the multivariate case?
2. How would I compute all the points in D that are within 2 std's (or the equivalent in the multivariate case) from the mean M?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the generalization that you want is the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance).  A Mahalanobis distance of 1 from the mean is the generalization of one standard deviation from the mean of a univariate Gaussian.

You can compute the Mahalanobis distance using functions in the module `scipy.spatial.distance`.  (There is almost certainly code for this distance in some form in scikit-learn, and possibly statsmodels, but I haven't checked.)

For computing a single distance, there is [`scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis.html), and for computing distances among or between collections of points, you can use [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) and [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), respectively (also from `scipy.spatial.distance`).

Here's a script that uses `cdist`. In the plot, the points circled in red are within a Mahalanobis distance of 2 from the mean.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist


# Mean
M = [10, 7]

# Covariance matrix
V = np.array([[ 9, -2],
              [-2,  2]])
VI = np.linalg.inv(V)

# Generate a sample from the multivariate normal distribution
# with mean M and covariance matrix V.
rng = np.random.default_rng()
x = rng.multivariate_normal(M, V, size=250)

# Compute the Mahalanobis distance of each point in the sample.
mdist = cdist(x, [M], metric='mahalanobis', VI=VI)[:,0]

# Find where the Mahalanobis distance is less than 2.
d2_mask = mdist < 2
x2 = x[d2_mask]

plt.plot(x2[:,0], x2[:,1], 'o',
         markeredgecolor='r', markerfacecolor='w', markersize=6, alpha=0.6)
plt.plot(x[:,0], x[:,1], 'k.', markersize=5, alpha=0.5)
plt.grid(alpha=0.3)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to define distance for the multivariate case is the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance), i.e.

An example of doing this would be:

```
import numpy as np

vals = np.array([[  6.83822474,   3.54843586],
                 [ 12.45778114,   4.42755159],
                 [ 10.27710359,   9.47337879],
                 [ 46.55259568,  64.73755611],
                 [ 51.50842754,  44.60132979]])

# Compute covariance matrix and its inverse
cov = np.cov(vals.T)
cov_inverse = np.linalg.inv(cov)

# Mean center the values
mean = np.mean(vals, axis=0)
centered_vals = vals - mean

# Compute Mahalanobis distance
dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(centered_vals * cov_inverse.dot(centered_vals.T).T, axis=1))

# Find points that are "far away" from the mean
indices = dist > 2
```

Comment: The question was asked about 2 hours ago, and your answer appears just *seconds* before I hit the submit button for mine.  Go figure.  Anyway, +1.

Comment: But yours is better so I'm upvoting it too :)